# Split a ConcurrentLinkedQueue into half using Spliterator

Tags: multithreading, split, java-8, partitioning, concurrent-queue

I have a ConcurrentLinkedQueue and I want to split it into two halves and let two separate threads handle each. I have tried using Spliterator but I do not understand how to get the partitioned queues.

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<int[]> q = // contains a large number of elements
Spliterator<int[]> p1 = q.spliterator();
Spliterator<int[]> p2 = p1.trySplit();
p1.getQueue(); 
p2.getQueue();
```

I want to but cannot do `p1.getQueue()` etc.

Please let me know the correct way to do it.

Comment: You can't split a queue into two queues using Spliterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't split it in half in general, I mean to split in half this queue must have a size at each point in time. And while `CLQ` does have a `size()` method, it's documentation is pretty clear that this size requires `O(n)` traversal time and because this is a `concurrent queue` it's size might not be accurate at all (it is named `concurrent` for a reason after all). The current `Spliterator` from `CLQ` splits it in batches from what I can see.

If you want to split it in half logically and process the elements, then I would suggest moving to some `Blocking` implementation that has a `drainTo` method, this way you could drain the elements to an `ArrayList` for example, that will split much better (half, then half again and so on).

On a side note, why would you want to do the processing in different threads *yourself*? This seems very counter-intuitive, the `Spliterator` is designed to work for parallel streams. Calling `trySplit` *once* is probably not even enough - you have to call it until it returns `null`... Either way doing these things on your own sounds like a very bad idea to me.

Comment: You don’t have to call it until it returns `null`. The logic is more complicated. But calling once is indeed not enough, especially when the source is a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

Comment: @Holger I assume not enough has to do with the fact that this is `concurrent` structure, right?

Comment: You already described the problem very well, it’s concurrent and it’s linked, so there is no easy way to split off the “right” number of elements, so the implementation starts with a tiny buffer for the first split, raising the buffer size on each subsequent split, so for a really large `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` you need quiet a number of `trySplit` calls before you get anywhere near the true half.